# How can I access the contents of this JSON encoded php array?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I've edited this question to reflect the answers below.

The array $animation is returned encoded from another function and contains strings of URL's like index.html, index1.html etc..

I generated animation using this function..

```
$select = "SELECT card_id, order_num FROM decks WHERE box_num=$box_num AND id=$userid ORDER BY order_num";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $select) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error($db));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $animation[] = array(
            'card_id' => $row['card_id'],
            'order_num' => $row['order_num'],
        );
    }

    return json_encode($animation);
```

The contents of $animation is

> "[{"card_id":"baby","order_num":"1"},{"card_id":"selectBaby","order_num":"2"},{"card_id":"bed","order_num":"3"},{"card_id":"selectBed","order_num":"4"},{"card_id":"book","order_num":"5"},{"card_id":"selectBook","order_num":"6"},{"card_id":"cup","order_num":"7"},{"card_id":"selectCup","order_num":"8"},{"card_id":"cupboard","order_num":"9"},{"card_id":"selectCupboard","order_num":"10"},{"card_id":"daddy","order_num":"11"},{"card_id":"selectDaddy","order_num":"12"},{"card_id":"eating","order_num":"13"},{"card_id":"mummy","order_num":"14"},{"card_id":"selectMummy","order_num":"15"},{"card_id":"plate","order_num":"16"},{"card_id":"selectPlate","order_num":"17"},{"card_id":"shoe","order_num":"18"},{"card_id":"selectShoe","order_num":"19"},{"card_id":"table","order_num":"20"},{"card_id":"selectTable","order_num":"21"},{"card_id":"walking","order_num":"22"},{"card_id":"selectWalking","order_num":"23"},{"card_id":"dogNose","order_num":"24"},{"card_id":"selectDogNose","order_num":"25"},{"card_id":"teddyEars","order_num":"26"},{"card_id":"selectTeddyEars","order_num":"27"},{"card_id":"ActivityOne","order_num":"28"},{"card_id":"ActivityTwo","order_num":"29"},{"card_id":"ActivityThree","order_num":"30"},{"card_id":"ActivityFour","order_num":"31"},{"card_id":"ActivityFive","order_num":"32"},{"card_id":"ActivitySix","order_num":"33"}]"

then I try to pass it javascript.

```
var url = <?php echo $animation; ?>;
alert(url); //check the for some data
```

The output of this code is

> Object object Object object Object object Object object Object object
>   Object object

The output I need is the card_id so I can pass it to the url eg: baby,bed,book etc

url url url url

I need the strings to do this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var suffix = ".html";
   $('#buffer').load('../Animations/' + url[0] + suffix);
   $('#buffer').trigger('create');    
});
```

Comment: add quotes: `var jsonUrl = '<?php echo $animation; ?>'`;

Comment: Is `$animation` already encoded?

Comment: Yes I returned it encoded from another function

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted :-/ It's a valid question. :(

Comment: What about showing us what `$animation` is? That would be helpful.

Comment: see edit above for how I generated $animation

Comment: @DavidFolksman: That's not terribly useful. Show the actual contents of the variable with `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Comment: Sorry, quite new to this.  I'll try and give it a go

Comment: ok I think I've done it and added it to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, check if the `<?php echo $animation; ?>` output a valid json
  string.
- Second, the `JSON.parse` is not supported by all browsers,
  you should use a library like `$.parseJSON` (from jquery)

In your case, if you do not output `"`, you don't need `JSON.parse` at all because the object is already a javascript object. Example: if the `<?php echo $animation; ?>` is rendered into something like `{x:1,y:2}`, your rendered javascript looks like this

```
var jsonUrl = {x:1,y:2};
```

It's already a javascript object

Comment: `JSON.parse` [is supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=json) even by IE 8. There is no need to involve jQuery unless you specifically need legacy support.

Comment: Yea when I `alert(url)` to the screen I get `Object object`, but how do I access each Object's contents?  I wanted to do some kind of loop, url[index] (index++)

Comment: When I alert(jsonUrl) I get "Object object" and not the literal string inside the object.

Comment: How can I access the string?

Comment: @David Folksman: alert(jsonUrl) I get "Object object". I'm sure that jsonUrl is already a javascript object. You don't need JSON.parse at all, just use it directly jsonUrl [index] (index++)

Comment: See above for new edit please.

Comment: @David Folksman: you already have the object. Why need a string? If you need a string, just put it in "" like this var jsonUrl = "<?php echo $animation; ?>";

Comment: See edit above, I need to iterate through the array and insert the url from each index to update a div on the page using jQuery.

Comment: @David Folksman: just use the jsonUrl directly like this: $('#buffer').load('../Animations/' + jsonUrl[0] + suffix);

Comment: Is that not what im doing in the above code? It doesn't work. I get `the error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (15:02:57:803 | error, network)
  at url/[object]` which is why I need the string.

Comment: @David Folksman: I think because this url "../Animations/' + jsonUrl[0] + suffix" points to a nonexistent address on the server.

Comment: Its appending the word "object" to the URL, instead of the actual URL.  If I manually edit it, it works fine.

Comment: @David Folksman:your url[0] is an object, you have to access a field like url[0].card_id or url[0].order_num

Comment: THATS DONE IT! Thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: @David Folksman: wellcome, that's the reason we're here. Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to create JSON anywhere. Unless `$animation` is already a JSON string, you need to do this:

```
var jsonUrl = <?php echo json_encode($animation); ?>;
```

Comment: best answer, there is not even a need to parse json in javascript, the way its printed from php is 100% compatible to javascript (thats why its call JavaScript Object Notation)

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that the array $animation is already encoded, I returned it encoded from another function.

Answer (score 2):

I Assume you have a valid `json` I think you can use `json_decode` to decode your json to an array. This function also support a third paramenter which, if given true, will return your json as an associative array.

Please read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I downvoted, because json_decode is aPHP function, not javascript.

Comment: question is tagged php and title also

Comment: But you obviously didn't read the content.